# The rebirth of a language from a group of mute people

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse, language

I am toying around with a corner case of a well explored scenario: post apocalyptic world human re-population.

The added complication this time is that the group of survivors, by a sheer strike of luck, are all functionally mute individuals: they were all able to speak their language, until after various accidents they cannot articulate any sound. For the rest they:

- are proficient in writing and reading the same language
- the language they know is phonetically simple (no weird phonemes like the English chemical element "*lead*" and present tense "*lead*")
- are proficient in the sign version of their language
- possess the needed mix of knowledge (theoretical and practical) to kick-start humanity
- have perfectly normal hearing
- recorded version of their language are somewhat available (songs, movies and so on) but, due to circumstances, not easily reproducible, in particular for the first few generations.

Based on what I know, infants learn a language by listening to adults speaking it. In this scenario there will be nobody to speak the language to the first generation. They will only learn the written, read and sign version of the language.

Under the above conditions, and assuming the population manages to grow over time, will they have a spoken language at all or not?

Comment: The first generation is functionally mute.  Is the second? When does the potential for speech re-enter society?

Comment: Seems to me in the scenario described, you would need something to stop them from forming a language.  The more unclear questions would be, over what time frame and how similar would the emergent language resemble the original preexisting one.

Comment: language arose in deaf humans deprived of language in about 4 years of regular interaction. so that is probably your fastest time.

Comment: *"Are proficient in the sign version of their language":* This is meaningless. There is no such thing as a "sign version" of a spoken language. For example, [American Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language) is not a version of English, it is a completely different language. (Fun factoid: American Sign Language is actually descended from the [French Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Sign_Language_family), and is not related to the [British Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Sign_Language)...)

Comment: What @AlexP points out is *crucial*. There is this notion that "sign language" is just "language X" (e.g. English) but in signs. And that you can map from one to the other and back 1:1. The movie Congo had a "sign language translator" technology and every other year there is news of one science team or another creating a version of it. But sign languages just don't work that way. There are several different sign languages used in otherwise English speaking countries. And the same sign language (or same family) can be used in countries with otherwise different spoken languages.

Comment: @AlexP -- Look up Signed English.

Comment: So I have a couple questions about your underlying assumptions: **1.** Phonetically simple, as a concept, is really a matter of taste of an outsider. Whatever your native language is, that's going to be "simple". **2.** Your example is confusing. All the phonemes seem pretty simple to me! /lɛd/ for both words. **3**  What do you actually mean by "functionally mute?"  Where does their mutism arise from?

Comment: @elemtilas The present tense of the verb "lead" is pronounced /lid/ (or /liːd/). I think OP was thinking of "weird homophones", or more precisely "irregular ortography"

Comment: @Vilarinof -- Oops! Still an easy phoneme!

Comment: Afaik "lead" is only a surprising coincidence :-)

Comment: @elemtilas I am trying to leave out "nightmares" like the following: “Ough” can be pronounced in eight different ways. The following sentence contains them all: “A rough-coated, dough-faced ploughman strode through the streets of Scarborough, coughing and hiccoughing thoughtfully."

Comment: @L.Dutch --- Yeah. That's a matter of English pronunciation getting all out of hand with respect to orthography. A reform of English pronunciation would do wonders! You might want to replace that bullet point with "the written language was originally devised to be a simple one letter to one phoneme scheme with regards to the original spoken language" or something to that effect! I'd still like clarity on No 3: what do you mean by "functionally mute"?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the first generation capable of speech would reinvent it. On the assumption that the mutism isn't heritable, and isn't caused by some environmental agent, that means it'll start happening within a few years of The Event.

Whilst stuff like [twin talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptophasia) might arise from children who spent almost all their time together from a very early age, it seems entirely possible that once some sort of [idiogloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioglossia) springs into existence spontaneously (and humans do seem wired for that sort of thing to happen) it'll bootstrap speech even in the absense of recordings of speech from before The Event. Compare with complex sign languages, which seem to arise spontaneously in various places at various times when there were sufficient deaf people present with a wish to communicate with each other (eg. [Origins of Sign Languages](https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/38678/chapter-abstract/335905322?login=false), though that's paywalled there are certainly other reasonable papers on the subject I can't track down right now).

Comment: Research of feral children would yield useful information I immagin.

Comment: @Gillgamesh feral children tend not to have any kind of socialization, and so not much language. There's some studies on groups of homeless children, but I can't find anything directly relevant right now and it all makes for some pretty depressing reading.

Comment: yes, not the most uplifting reading but the rabbit hole eventually leads to related concepts like; https://research.library.mun.ca/10241/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_deprivation

Comment: @Gillgamesh, it's the languages used by groups of children of disparate immigrant populations that give the information you're after. They don't have a common language, but they very quickly develop one with full grammar out of bits of all the languages they have. See irregular conjugations of yeet as a modern western version of this.

Comment: @Separatrix Interesting but in this particular environment. there is little preexisting language to draw upon. The only source for the emergent language is the not-so-readily available recordings the OP states. No real world parallels for this particular scenario. Both lines are valid paths to explore.

Comment: @Gillgamesh this will be another 3rd path, as they have a full and complete language, but not the sounds to go with it. It will still be the children as children together who solve that problem, because there's no group more creative than children who haven't yet been taught that they have to obey a set of arbitrary rules.